# ラズベリーパイでpythonファイルを実行しても反応がない

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

[Raspberry piで音声認識(julius)を使用して特定の言葉に反応](https://qiita.com/fishkiller/items/c6c5c4dcd9bb8184e484)
のvoice2.pyを作成して実行したのですが実行後エラーすら出ずに

### 下記のように何の反応もしません。

> $python voice2.py
>   (...)

---

どうすればいいでしょうか？
それ以前のところはすべて完了しています。
((...)のところには何も表示されていません)

Answer (score 4):

Raspberry pi のことはさっぱり知りませんが、voice2.py のコードを見る限り、「julius からデータが送られるまで何もしないで待つ」という正常動作なのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

どこで止まっているかわからないので、とりあえずあちこちにprint文を入れて表示されるかどうか調べるのが早いと思います。